# How can I prove that $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, brownian-motion

Let $\Omega=[0,\infty)$, $A=B([0,\infty))$ and $P$ be a probability measure on $A$ which has a density. Define two stochastic processes $(X(t):t\ge 0)$ and $(Y(t):t\ge 0)$ by
\begin{align}
X(t)(\omega)&=\begin{cases}1 & \text{if }t=\omega \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}\\
Y(t)(ω)&=0
\end{align}

How can I prove that $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution?

Comment: You may specify what kind of density you are dealing with

Comment: that what i have in the exercise